Facing SSH timeout in different VMs on running ansible playbook - VMs created through terraform and tf modules, using custom image
I am trying to create an environment of 7 VMs through terraform code - creating NICs, and VMs (NSG, RG, Subnet already created) and I used a custom RHEL8 image.
Once I create my VMs, I "configure" them using ansible playbooks via jenkins. The problem arises in this configure stage. In each run after 12-13 minutes 1-3 of the VMs get disconnected with the below errors
fatal: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 641, "msg": "timed out waiting for ping module test: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 10.22.136.194 port 22: Connection timed out"}
or
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Broken pipe\r\nssh: connect to host 10.22.136.195 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
I connected with a MS support engineer and he the said NIC's were not getting joint correctly but couldn't elaborate more on that
Note - the same infrastructure and pipelines worked well with a custom CENTOS7 image, ssh timeout occurred but it wasn't a blocker like this time is
I tried destroying and re-creating, changing the ssh timeout limit in ansible.cfg (did not work), and connected with an MS support engineer but no resolution yet
The above setup should

Provision the VMs, disks, NICs - associate the NICs
configure the VMs - setup yum, oracle python etc without getting disconnected

Here is my main.tf where I create the VM and NIC
`resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nw_interface" {
  count = var.vm_count
  name                = "nic-${var.customer_acronym}-${var.env_acronym}-${var.vm_name}00${count.index + 1}-01"
  location            = var.rg.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vm-${var.customer_acronym}-${var.env_acronym}-${var.vm_name}0${count.index + 1}-network-configuration"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.pvt_ip_allocation
  }

  tags = merge(var.tags, tomap({"Name" = "vm-${var.customer_acronym}-${var.env_acronym}-${var.vm_name}00${count.index + 1}", "Role" = var.role}))

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "azure_vm" {
  count = var.vm_count
  name                  = "vm-${var.customer_acronym}-${var.env_acronym}-${var.vm_name}00${count.index + 1}"
  location              = var.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = var.rg.name
  vm_size                = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids = [element(azurerm_network_interface.nw_interface.*.id, count.index)]

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = var.del_disk_on_termination

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = var.del_disk_on_termination

  storage_image_reference {
  id = var.vm_image_id
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "disk-${var.customer_acronym}-${var.env_acronym}-${var.vm_name}0${count.index + 1}-disk"
    caching           = var.disk_opts.caching
    create_option     = var.disk_opts.create_option
    managed_disk_type = var.disk_opts.managed_disk_type
    disk_size_gb      = var.os_disk_size
    os_type           = var.disk_opts.os_type
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.vm_name}0${count.index + 1}"
    admin_username = var.admin_username
    admin_password = var.admin_password
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = var.disable_password_authentication
  }

  tags = merge(var.tags, tomap({"Name" = "vm-${var.customer_acronym}-${var.env_acronym}-${var.vm_name}00${count.index + 1}", "Role" = var.role}))

}`

this is my variables.tf mentioning the image
variable "image_name" { default = "rhlel8-base-image-2024-09-16" description = "Image name from which Dev VM would be created" }
NOTE - inserting what the support engineer said
"Troubleshooting Taken: The issue seems to be related to the network not coming up, as indicated by the logs showing many VMware references. It is suspected that the base image might not be prepared for Azure."
(https://i.sstatic.net/XIw4DbLc.png)

Can you connect over SSH without Ansible?

not to the VMs in failed state - even with manual ssh it gives timeout


Facing SSH timeout in different VMs

The blocker is with the custom image which is not set for azure. In general check with image network agent and networkiing setting.
you can try using more timeout in you ansible so that machine might be have enough time to set connection and in addition try adding retries then test the Test direct SSH access to problematic VMs using
ssh -v <vm_user>@<vm_ip_address>

As per the SO thread try the following approaches as mentioned
Try to enable to ansible_user instead of ansible_ssh_user and same as for password
ansible 192.168.15.29 -i your_hosts_file -m ping -e "ansible_ssh_user=remote ansible_ssh_pass=password"

or
ansible 192.168.15.29 -i your_hosts_file -m ping -e "ansible_user=remote ansible_password=password" 

This changes should be made in your ansible file &  ping my hosts using the -c paramiko option.
Refer:
Ansible fails to connect with SSH (banner exchange) - Stack Overflow by Ripper Tops

Thank you! I also found a workaround - I was setting hostnames through ansible after the VMs were provisioned, but we realised that hostnames needed to be set as part of the terraform provision
So I added a resource block for azurerm_virtual_machine_extension and set hostname through that
